# How to animate a function plot

Tags: functions, animation

How can I plot a function e.g. `f[x_] := Sin[x]`, point by point (animation).

Answer (score 12):

This is one way of doing it to get you started:

```
ListAnimate@Table[
  Plot[
    Cos[x], {x, 0, xmax}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}}
  ],
  {xmax, 2 \[Pi]/20, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/20}
]
```

[image: cosine animation]

Comment: Can you explain me what is the meaning of this {xmax, 2 \[Pi]/20, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/20}?

Comment: @User The syntax for the second `Table` argument in general is `{start,end,stepsize}`. In this case we want to get from `0` to `2Pi` in 20 steps, but since we also use `xmax` as maximum for `x` in `Plot`, `xmax==0` would cause problems, that's why we start with an offset at `xmax==2Pi/20`. Alternatively we could also write `With[{dx=2Pi/20}, ListAnimate@Table[Plot[...],{xmax,dx,2Pi,dx}]]`, which is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use Manipulate. Then you customize this in many ways.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 If[running,
  tick = Not[tick];
  xmax = xmax + Pi/40;
  If[xmax > 4 Pi, xmax = Pi/40]
  ];
 Pause[pause];
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, xmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
  PlotStyle -> Red]
 ,
 Grid[{{
    Button["run", running = True; tick = Not[tick]],
    Button["stop", running = False; tick = Not[tick]],
    Button["slow down", pause = pause + 1/10; tick = Not[tick]],
    Button["speed up", If[pause > 0, pause = pause - 1/10]]
    }}
  ],
 {{tick, True}, None},
 {{xmax, Pi/40}, None},
 {{running, False}, None},
 {{pause, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick, running}
 ]
```

Comment: A helpful tutorial on animations in Mathematica is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S03e6dwM100

Comment: @Lee the use of `For` and `Print` and relatively inefficient construction of those animations in that video made me sad ;_;